# How to run Appium with an iOS app

Tags: ios, appium

How do you use Appium with iOS? I know this question seems ridiculously simple, but actually you'd be surprised. There is apparently no documentation online that explains how to do this, except for perhaps youtube videos, which I can't watch anyway because my workplace disallows it.

I have a Mac. I have an app that is loaded in Xcode. I have the Appium desktop app running.

What do I do now?

BTW, I am already very familiar with Appium, as I have created tests for the Android version of the app.

Comment: Yes, I feel the same as you do. I think you need to setup your environment in your computer on first step.
Follow, understand how to write the script. Final, run it. This is the script example, https://qxf2.com/blog/python-appium-scroll-through-search-result-table/ .

Answer (score -2):

**Steps**

1. install **homebrew**: to install and update the required packages easily
2. install **Node.js**
3. install **Appium**
4. install **libimobiledevice**: required to run our tests on real 
   devices
5. install **ios-deploy**: required to deploy our apps to our devices
6. you also need **WebDriverAgent**: to opens the apps when it is downloaded to the device

Visit [IOS Mobile Test Automation Using Appium and JAVA](https://www.swtestacademy.com/ios-mobile-test-automation-appium/) to learn how to install and run appium with an ios app. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @NSNoob i was just trying to help him guiding him to the link so that he can solve his problem. Am i doing anything wrong?